# Item selected in listview using c# for CF

Tags: c#

I have listview with multiselected property is true. In listview I have Item like this:

Name                                        Type

f1.csv                                    .csv file

f2.txt                                    .txt file

f3.pdf                                     .pdf file

f4.log                                      .log file

As we   have multiselect property is true. So user can select more than one item at a time.I have one menuItem which is called property. So user can select any item and can see it's property.
Suppose user has first select f1.csv and then f2.txt but user want to see the property of f2.txt so he has to deselect the f1.csv.

Problem is that property is showing of f1.csv not f2.txt. So whatever item I have de-select, seems that It's taking as current select item.

2) problem is that when press cancle after seeing the property item is still selected. I want it to de-select on that time.

### here are code on click on property menuitem:::

```
if(_listView.SelectedItem != null)
            {


                _listView.SelectedIndex = _latestSelectedIndex;
                _listView.SelectedItem.Selected = true;
                _fileInfoViewer = new FileInfoViewer((DclFileInfoEx)_listView.SelectedItem.Tag,this._dclFileSystem);
                _fileInfoViewer.Closed += new EventHandler(_fileInfoViewer_Closed);
                _fileInfoViewer.ShowMe(this);
            }
```

Thanks in advance for answer.

Comment: what does CF stand for?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would rather change the form showing the properties. Pass all the selected items to the form constructor and then implement some buttons to move next /previous in the list of files selected

Comment: CF stnad for compact framework

Comment: if(_listView.SelectedItem != null)
    {
       
                    _listView.SelectedIndex = _latestSelectedIndex;
                    _listView.SelectedItem.Selected = true;
     _fileInfoViewer = new FileInfoViewer((DclFileInfoEx)_listView.SelectedItem.Tag,this._dclFileSystem);
     _fileInfoViewer.Closed += new EventHandler(_fileInfoViewer_Closed);
     _fileInfoViewer.ShowMe(this);
    }

Comment: Add your code to the original question, not in comments. It is hardly readable here

Comment: @ steve: when I click on property menuitem it is opening a new form with some text like size of selected file etc....